# Troubles after installing Two stores with same php docroot

Tags: magento

I am trying to setup multiple stores within same hosting account and I studied many interesting guides out there on the matter.

Seems to me I figured out simplest solution for me - map both my dot com sites onto the same directory on host, and modify .htaccess to launch different website depending on URL, like so:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*anatscraftonia.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="anatscraftonia";
SetEnvIf Host .*anatscraftonia.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE="website";
```

My first store works fine, but when I go to anatscraftonia.com , all I get always is a Magento 404 page.
I checked all settings, multiple stores are defined and code above is copy/paste from Admin console under Website I added. I have Home page enabled for All Stores and Base URL redefined for both Secure/Unsecure. I also tried changing website to store, with no improvements.

What else am I missing? How do I even know what page is it trying to go to, or whether it even gets “no-route” or just totally whacked…

Comment: Try doing step-by-step debugging, and you'll see what really happens...

Comment: This is on PHP installed on shared host. I rather not have to recreate database, Apache with PHP on my local computer. Of course even if I do recreate the whole thing, no guarantees that I will even have the same issue.
I can change PHP files to provide more logging or hints, but I am not sure which file(s) to change.

Comment: Working directly on the production server is bad practice... you should not recreate what exists on the production server on your local machine, but the other way round, once it works on your local computer. Problems that occur only on the production server are not rare, so this local copy would really be useful several times, especially with something as complex as Magento. Anyway, the other choice you have, adding more verbosity is just as, or even more painful.

Comment: Well, it's just a little store I am trying to setup for my wife. Definitely cutting corners, but was looking forward to some tips on where to add logging (or what else to check) to catch this, since as you noted, Magento is complex!

Answer (score 1):

I threw together some quick and dirty code a few years ago to log the controller dispatch process in Magento Community 1.3x.

http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_dispatch_logging

I don't think you'll be able to drop those files into a current installation, but it should give you an idea where to stick some logging functions to see why Magento is routing to a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but why not use a single instance of magento to handle both stores and magentos own multi store capability..

full details here http://dx3webs.com/front/2010/08/magento-multistore-setup-under-plesk/ post contains links to cpanel instructions as well.

the instructions are for multiple domains but will work with sub folders

Comment: I do need multiple domains with single magento installation and these instructions are pretty much what I did. But, I ran into a limitation of my host where I can't have shell access to link my folders, so instead I physically pointed both domains to same directory via cPanel.